# React Router: How do I display only the component content without App.js content when clicking on the Navbar button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a problem in my page.

I have a navbar containing a button that should take me to login page using router, but when I click on it, it did take me to `"/login"`, but the content of login component adds to the content of App.js. Instead, I want just the content of the login component to show.

This is the App.js code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Routes, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import About from './AboutPage/About';
import Login from './Login';
import CA from './CA'
import './App.css'
import `gifImage` from './output-`onlinegiftools`.gif';


`function` App() {
  return (
    <div ``className``='App'>
    <Router>
            <div `className`='presentation'>
            <nav>
                <Link to='/About' `your text`className='link'><h1>app</h1></Link>
                <div `className`='login'>
                <Link to="/CA" className="link"><p>Create Account</p></Link>
                <Link to="/Login" className="link"><button>Login Now</button></Link>
                <Outlet />
                </div>
            </nav>
            <h1 className='h11'>********* <br /> ********</h1>
            <div className="GIF">
              <img src={gifImage} alt="Example GIF" />
            </div>
            </div>

            <div className='part2'>
            <p class="new">New Features Available</p>
            <h1>**************</h1>
            <p>******************************************************** <br /> **************************** <br />******************** <br /> **********..</p>
            <button>Login for More</button>
            </div>

            <Routes>
                <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
                <Route path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="/CA" element={<CA render={true} />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

I want to display only the content of login and CA (create account) component when clicking on the navbar, but when I, do the content of App.js get displayed too

Comment: The code in your question is full of syntax errors, mostly around unnecessary backtick characters. I understand these probably came from the (horrible) _Ask Question Wizard_ but could you please [edit] it to provide valid JSX code?

Answer (score 2):

Extract the content to be shown on the home page to a separate component and render that only for the path `/`.

Home.js:

```
export default function Home() {
    return <>
        <h1 className='h11'>********* <br /> ********</h1>
        <div className="GIF">
          <img src={gifImage} alt="Example GIF" />
        </div>
        { /* move the code that should not be shown on every page here... */ }
    </>;
}
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
    // ...
    return (
        // other elements... (keep the common elements here)
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/CA" element={<CA render={true} />} />
        </Routes>
    );
}
```